# Is conditioning always increase the probability of some event

Tags: probability, self-study

Is conditioning always increase the probability of some event ?
My answer is, since by conditioning we are reducing the sample space probability must increase.
Am I correct??? If not please explain me

Answer (score 2):

Of course not, for example $P(A|A’)$ is $0$; because given that $A$ did not happen, it’ll be impossible for $A$ to happen.